# No puedo encontrar el archivo con php

Tags: php

Me podrian ayudar con esto:

```
<?php

$archivo="datos.txt";
$camino="datos/";
if(file_exists($camino.$archivo))
{
print " <p> Si existe el archivo $archivo en la carpeta $camino. </p>";
}
else
{
print " <p> No existe el archivo $archivo en la carpeta $camino. </p>";
}
?>
```

> es una validacion de la existencia de un archivo pero solo va por el
>   else. No entiendo que esta mal, por que dice que no existe?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo ejecuté como script y funciona correctamente. Prueba poniendo un `var_dump(getcwd());` a ver si la ruta inicial que está usando es justo donde se encuentra el directorio `datos`.

Answer (score 0):

Otra solucion puede ser usando lo siguiente:

```
<?php
    $basePath = dirname(realpath(__FILE__));
    $archivo="datos.txt";
    $camino="/datos/";
    if(file_exists($basePath.$camino.$archivo))
    {
        print " <p> Si existe el archivo $archivo en la carpeta $camino.</p>";
    }
    else
    {
        print " <p> No existe el archivo $archivo en la carpeta $camino.</p>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto y me avisas

```html
<?PHP
 $archivo="datos.txt";
    $path = "./filespath/"; //set the path of the folder that contains the files
    $newpath=substr($path,2);//this takes out the ./ of the path
    $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path");
    while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)){
    if($file!="." && $file!=".." && is_file($path.$file) && $file==$archivo){
  echo "se encontró el archivo";
  break;
 }
    }
?>
```

Comment: en SO en español no solo se esperan respuestas que son fragmentos de código que el OP debe probar para ver si funcionan; además de eso debes incluir una breve explicación teórica pues este recurso le debe ser útil a todos y todas las que consulten tu respuesta, por favor revisa [answer] y agrega que hace ese script y por que sería la solución al OP